# programmatically trimming (automatically cropping out transparent boundaries) an image in objective-c / cocoa

Tags: iphone, graphics, image-processing, image-manipulation

Does anyone know how to trim an image (uiimage or cgimage). By trim I mean programatically cropping to the non-transparent bounds of an image. So if I have the image below:

- 00111000
- 00010000
- 01011110
- 00000000

it would yield:

- 011100
- 001000
- 101111

Comment: i should add that i can easily extract the image data into another context and from there find the RGBA values, and then look for transparent values and reduce the image appropriately, and then draw back to an image... BUT i was wondering if there is a simpler / quicker way. thx

Answer (score 4):

Sum all rows and all columns of your image. You'll get two arrays, in your example looking like this:

```
3 1 5 0
0 1 1 3 2 1 1 0
```

Then the first non-zero from the left and the last one near the right is where you have to crop, in each direction.